# how add the entry ij-th of a matrix to a data Fram who has column i and row j

Tags: r, matrix

I have a data frame. with two column A and B. I want add one more column C to this from a matrix where the Column A is i and column B is j. for example suppose I have

```
          A        B
          1        3
          2        2
```

and I have a matrix

M:

```
    1     3     0 
    2     4      5
    2     1     6
```

the new column C is first row and tired column and second row and second column:

```
          A        B       C
          1        3       0
          2        2       4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the data.frame to matrix and use that as row/column index to extract the values from 'M' and assign it to new column in 'df1'

```
df1['C'] <-  M[as.matrix(df1)]
df1
#  A B C
#1 1 3 0
#2 2 2 4
```

Or another option is to `cbind` (which by default creates a `matrix`) the extracted columns from data.frame

```
df1['C'] <- M[cbind(df1$A, df1$B)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:2, B = c(3, 2))
M <- cbind(c(1, 2, 2), c(3, 4, 1), c(0, 5, 6))
```

Comment: this much simple? I will try

Comment: how about if I have more columns ? where I should put A and B in that case

Comment: @shere In that case, just subset the dataset, i.e. `M[as.matrix(df1[c("A", "B")])]` or use the `cbind` method updated

Comment: the only problem is for row i and column j, it gives me (i+1)(j)-th entry

Comment: @shere Not clear, I get the 0, 4 as in the expected output

Comment: I know I think my data set has a problem. I'll try to fix it